# "Hi Joe" vs. "Hi Mr Parker" when writing an email

Tags: word-usage, formality

Joseph Parker is an English tutor and he likes his students call him Joe. By tutor, I mean he doesn't teach at college or school. He teaches English with an online classroom. Which probably means it's more casual to talk with him than with my professor in college.

I guess it's appropriate to call him Joe in classroom. The question is how to address him in email.

When I write an email to him, should I start with "Hi Joe" or "Hi Mr Parker"?

Comment: The decision is yours. Using his first name is informal and would be suitable if he was a friend or, as you indicate, liked being addressed as Joe. In most cases, a pupil would address a tutor by his surname.

Comment: Hello Joe or Dear Joe. Of course not Mr, as he has already informed you.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you. What he informed me is for classroom, which is more casual than email, right?

Comment: Not at all. Once a person has said, "Call me Joe", it can be used in any written or spoken communication. There is no such thing as "Call me Joe" but if you write to me use Mr. Culturally speaking, I mean.

Answer (score 0):

It is up to you and depends a little on the purpose of the email.  If it is about a relatively formal matter I'd use Mr. Parker.

> Dear Mr Parker,
>
> I regret that I will not be completing this course as I have decided to focus my language studies on Dutch instead of English.

On the other hand if the matter relatively casual:

> Dear Joe,
>
> Here's the homework you set.  I've done pages 2 and 3 but I had trouble with question 5. Could you explain that next lesson?

The same applies in many other situations.  I'd normally call my boss "Paul" (in emails and face to face.  But if I was writing a letter of resignation or complaint, I'd use Mr Furrow.